# Find element and replace it

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to make a function (or use library) that will search the array of objects find specific one by its property and replace it with the other object. E.g.:

```
var a = {name: "Jane", age: 29}

var arr = [{name: "Chris", age: 20}, {name: "Jane", age: 45}] 

arr.find(person => { if (a.name === person.name) {person = a})
```

Is there such a function?

Edit: 
It would be nice if there is no matched object in array it would push it to an array that object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findhttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method, as such:

```
var jane = {name: "Jane", age: 29}

var persons = [
    {name: "Chris", age: 20}, 
    {name: "Jane", age: 45}
];

function findPerson(person) {
    return function(element, index, array) {
        if(person.name === element.name) {
            array[index] = person;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

persons.find(findPerson(jane));
```

This would replace the matched person if found and else returns undefined. So you could check if undefined is returned and add the person afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

I can only think of [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var a = {name: "Jane", age: 29}

var arr = [{name: "Chris", age: 20}, {name: "Jane", age: 45}] 

arr = arr.map(function(o){

   // if names match, return new object
   // otherwise, return original object
   return o.name == a.name ? a : o;

});

console.log( arr );
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for a wrapper around [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Your example would look like this:

```
arr.forEach((elem, index) => {
  if (elem.name !== a.name) return
  arr.splice(index, 1, a)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to modify the original array, you can use `array#forEach()`, just iterate through the array and replace the object which matches your `a` object name.

```js
var a = {name: "Jane", age: 29}
var arr = [{name: "Chris", age: 20}, {name: "Jane", age: 45}] 

arr.forEach((person,index) => { 
if (a.name === person.name)
  arr[index] = a;
})
console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```